# How to stop execution at a certain point in visual basic 6?

Tags: vb6

What I want to do is execute my program and pause and go to the line where it paused. For example, for inspecting data before sending a form.
I tried with ctrl + pause button but it only pauses the execution.
How can I acheive this?

Comment: Yes, I meant vb6

Comment: I tried F9 but it doesnt work

Comment: @DexterNaru if you really meann VB6 ,then change the tag on your Q

Comment: `I tried F9 but it doesnt work` - it does, when your caret is on the right line.

Comment: Do you see the red circle to the left of the line where you place the breakpoint (F9 or just clicking there with the mouse)?

Comment: What line are you trying to place it on?  It won't work if you place it an a `Dim`.  It might help if you show your code where you want to place the breakpoint.

Comment: I didn't place any breakpoint. I want to see what code is executing while I interact with my program

Comment: You need to place a breakpoint in your `Main` or add a watch to interrupt your program on some condition so you can step through it.  There are some 3rd party tools that allow profiling https://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html

Comment: Best ways:
- Left click in the thin gutter to the left of code and see a RED circle appear (line turns red).
- Click somewhere onto the line of text and press F9.
- Insert a blank line and place the statement `Stop` (Can also be in an if condition).

From there, use F8 to step into, Shft-F8 to step over, and Ctl-Shft-F8 to step out of.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Break` does the thing. There's no `Break` key on my laptop keyboard so I have to press `Ctrl+Fn+B` instead.

If you want, you can open the call stack window after that (`View->Call Stack...`) and see where's your execution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

are you talking in debug while writing the code in the Vb6 IDE(before it's compiled?). Just left click the grey frame to the left of the line of code in the editor, where you want to set a break point at (the line will show the default maroon font backcolor and a little round dot will appear to the line of the code in that grey frame). run the source (f5) and your code will 'pause' at that break point you added. Alternatively, right click the line of code, choose toggle, then breakpoint - (under toggle you can also set, Break On All Errors, Break on Class etc). F8 lets you step through your code in the Vb6 IDE

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about the `Stop` statement.